# Java JTable guadar cualquier dato en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

estoy realizando un proyecto y estoy tratando de hacer en un JTable agregar datos a la MySQL a través de la JTable hasta ahí todo funciona bien, pero si yo quiero rellenar un solo campo de la fila me retorna null porque no llene la fila completa

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

````
    public void Save() {

        try {

            String SQL = "INSERT INTO PrimeroA (`Cedula`, `Apellido y Nombre`, `1er Lap`, `2do Lap`, `3er Lap`, `Matematica`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                    + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Apellido y Nombre` = VALUES (`Apellido y Nombre`), `1er Lap` = VALUES (`1er Lap`), `2do Lap` = VALUES (`2do Lap`), `3er Lap` = VALUES (`3er Lap`), `Matematica` = VALUES (`Matematica`)";

            Connection = ConnectionBD.getConnection();

            if (tblPrimerA.getRowCount() > 0) {

                for (int row = 0; row < tblPrimerA.getRowCount(); row++) {

                    ps = Connection.prepareStatement(SQL);

                    ps.setString(1, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
                    ps.setString(2, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
                    ps.setString(3, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
                    ps.setString(4, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
                    ps.setString(5, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
                    ps.setString(6, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());

                    int up = ps.executeUpdate();

                    if (up > 0) {
                        System.out.println("data up");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("failed up");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("no hay datos en la jtable");
            }

            Connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrqd3.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfRca.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukbqB.png
````

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste el código como imagen?. No es lo mismo enviar a una sentencia preparada el valor `null` que la cadena `"null"`.

Comment: Había colocado la sentencia para que el for pueda recorrer las demás filas ya que solo se quedaba en la primera fila y no recorría las demás

Comment: Si el valor puede ser nulo no deberías hacer `toString()`; prueba con `ps.setObject()`.

Comment: Ahora si funciona correctamente, pero a la vez me surge una duda el único campo que no puede ser null es 'Cedula' la Primary key, en ese caso que me recomendarías hacer?

Comment: Hay varias maneras de manejarlo profesionalmente, casi cuestión de gustos; de entrada no usaría un TableModel para una sentencia preparada. En tu caso podría bastar con que hicieras un cast: `setString(1, (String)tm.getValueAt(r,c));` o con que bajes el valor a una variable y la uses.

Comment: Aún me lanzaba que "no podía ser nulo", así que cree otra variable llamada ID Auto_Increment y puse la variable 'Cedula' como UNIQUE, pero pasa que si guardo varias veces se repitos mismo datos por la ID Auto_increment

Comment: Puse los demás también como unique, pero sería mejor solo colocar UNIQUE a Cedula  y Apellido y Nombre?

Comment: La solución fue hacer que el botón 'Guardar' este desactiva y se activará cuando se ingresen datos en la JTable

Answer (score 0):

@Hector, el **if** que incluiste en el método, hace exactamente eso, si hay un valor **null**, no se entra al **if**.

Tal vez te sirva usar algo así:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    if( tblPrimerA.getValueAt( row, i ) != null ) {
        ps.setString( i, tblPrimerA.getValueAt( row, i ).totring();
    }
    else {
        ps.setString( i + 1, "" );
    }
}
```

Comment: No funciono, pero muchas gracias de igual manera